# Inverse mapping does not working well on default functions

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

Sorry but i'm new to mapstruct,
lets say we have Door, Car classes & DoorDTO, CarDTO as shown below,

Do i have to write the inverse function of doorsToDoorsDTO to get carDTOToCar works correctly??

Note: i added @InheritInverseConfiguration on doorsToDoorsDTO but still the generated code is not right !

```
public class Door{
    Long id;
    String name;
    String color;
    ..
    ..
}

public class DoorDTO {
Long id;
String name;
}

public class Car {
    List<Door> doors;
}

public class CarDTO {
    List<DoorDTO> doorDTOs;
}

@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
    CarDTO carToCarDTO(Car car);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    Car carDTOToCar(CarDTO carDTO);

    List<Door> doorsToDoorsDTO(List<Door> doors){
        List<DoorDTO> doorDTOs = new ArrayList<>();

        doors.foreach(door -> {
            DoorDTO doorDTO = new DoorDTO();
            doorDTO.setId(door.getId());
            doorDTO.setName(door.getName());
            doorDTOs .add(doorDTO);
        });
        return doorDTOs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct will generate the lists for you..

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
    CarDTO carToCarDTO(Car car);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    Car carDTOToCar(CarDTO carDTO);

    DoorDTO doorToDoorDTO(Door door);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    Door doorDToDoor(DoorDTO doorDTO);
}
```